# pyspark json not able to inferschema for empty

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

In Pyspark, whenever i read a json file with an empty set element. The entire element is ignored in the resultant DataFrame.
Sample json :
{logs :[],pagination:{}}

And it only ignores the second element, i.e pagination in the above example. is there anyway to read the json with proper schema.?

Comment: you can provide the schema upon reading the dataframe like [`spark.read.schema(...)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.schema.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.schema)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can perform in two ways with schema and without schema:

**Reading Json `with` schema:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType,LongType

schema = StructType([StructField('email', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('first_name', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('gender', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('id', LongType(), True),
                     
                     StructField('last_name', StringType(), True)])

df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(r'dbfs:/FileStore/MOCK_DATA__1_.json')
```

[image]

[image]

**Reading Json `Without` schema**

d1 = spark.read.json(r'dbfs:/FileStore/MOCK_DATA__1_.json')
d1.show()

[image]